# SQL where condition to retrieve same data that is in two separate tables, in alphabetical order

Tags: sql

I have two separate tables and wish to retrieve the names of those of whom are listed in both?

The tables are football, rugby. fields: Forename, Surname.

Comment: That's nice to know.  Now...to help you we need to know more about 1) your tables, 2) what you've done so far.  Give us something and we'll gladly help.

Comment: Hello Peter, and welcome to stackoverflow. As asked, you are unlikely to get an answer to your question because it lacks any detail. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for tips on improving your question.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry about that, and thanks for the responses.

Comment: What have you done so far? -> http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 3):

You essentially want the intersection between the two tables, this is achieved using the `intersect` operator:

```
select forename, surname
from rugby
intersect
select forename, surname
from football
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/3354e7/1

Comment: Thank you, sorry about the lack of detail.